# Static Assert to check compile-time-constant is NOT passed to macro

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfinae, static-assert, compile-time-constant

**Preamble:**

```
switch(nValue)
{
case X:
...
case Y:
...
default:
   ASSERT_FOR_DEFAULT(nValue);
}
```

`ASSERT_FOR_DEFAULT` is a macro, that will display a (custom) assertion dialog, to report hitting "default-case". Yes, this macro is for run-time assertion, not for compile time assertion. But, I just need that, any constant-value (compile-time) cannot be passed to this macro.

**Problem:**

Following should **fail** at compilation:

```
ASSERT_FOR_DEFAULT(5);
```

Yes, programmer may use it anywhere, not just in `default` case of a `switch-case`. He may also use any expression which is not used in `switch`. But that's not the issue. Just need that only non-constant should be passed to this macro.

There is nothing important written for this macro, just assume it is `ASSERT`/`assert`.

I have tried with templates (used them other SFINAE/static-asserts!), arrays (like `strcpy_s`), own struct having `YES`, `NO` types and what not. But couldn't find the solution!

I am using VC2008. I am aware of `static_assert`, `decltype` etc, but cannot use C++0x.

---

**EDIT (Solution):**

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(expr) {int array[!!(expr)]; expr;}

template <class T>  
bool noConstAllowed(T&);

int noConstAllowed(...);

#define ASSERT_FOR_DEFAULT_VALUE(val)                \
{                                                  \
    STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(noConstAllowed(val))==sizeof(bool));   \
}

int main()
{
    int test=10;

    ASSERT_FOR_DEFAULT_VALUE(test);
    ASSERT_FOR_DEFAULT_VALUE(2);
    ASSERT_FOR_DEFAULT_VALUE(test+2);  //FAILS, but okay for me! 
}
```

Thanks to Arne Mertz for this lovely suggestion. I derived the solution from it. 
`noConstAllowed` is overloaded for all `T&` types, and if constant value is passed, the another overload will be called. Both have different return types, and thus checking against the size. Templated version returns a `bool`, which satisfies the assert for any variable passed, and fails for any constant, or expression (since return type would be `int`).

Comment: @aleguna, Pointless comment! I need expression for static-assert, not how to make or use static-assert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine the macro so that it takes the address of the parameter - that should fail for literals. However that will not prevent you from passing a constant variable, e.g.

```
const static int FIVE = 5;
ASSERT_FOR_DEFAULT(FIVE); // still works.
```

To prohibit *all* kinds of constants from being passed to your macro call a function that takes the parameter by non-const reference:

```
template <class T>  void noConstAllowed(T&){};
#define ASSERT_FOR_DEFAULT_VALUE(val)                \
  {                                                  \
    (void*)&(val);         /* no literals*/          \
    noConstAllowed(val);   /* no constants at all */ \
    switchHitDefaultDialog(val, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
  }
```

I suppose you use something like **FILE** or other positional macros or you would have made it a function. Of yourse, you only need to use one of the two lines.

Comment: Nice suggestion! The solution you gave isn't static-assert, but with overloading, template and different return type for 'noConstAllowed' and with sizeof, I would craft a SA for it.

Comment: Made it. Thank you! Check my edited question for the solution I found.